# Multi provider relational user table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

I am new in laravel and trying to create an auth system where user can login/register using multiple providers and whenever user logins using any of providers the user avatar and profile data must be shown accordingly. When using `Auth::user()->providers` the result is array of all registered providers for that user.

What I want is to fetch only provider data for current login method (i.e local account, facebook account provider, google account provider etc) so I can show data from that exact provider for user.

User.php

```
...
    public function providers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\UserProvider");
    }
...
```

UserProvider.php

```
class UserProvider Extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_providers';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'provider', 'provider_id','avatar_url', 'token', 'token_secret',
    ];

}
```

Please let me know if I am on the right way or is there any other way to do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your relation to build a query

```
$provider = Auth::user()->providers()->where('provider', 'facebook')->first();
```

This will return single UserProvider class object

Answer (score 1):

You could also include a boolean column in your `user_providers` table to know which of the providers is the last used (so this will be the current login method). Let's call this column `is_current`.

So, when a user access the system, you update the login method setting this field to `true`. You can do this by overriding the `authenticated()` method of the `app\Http\Controllers\LoginController` controller:

```
# app\Http\Controllers\LoginController.php

protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    Auth::user()
          ->providers()
          ->where('provider', $request->provider) // Change this to make it work
          ->update('is_current', true);
}
```

This way, you can access your current login method wherever you want, doing this:

```
Auth::user()->providers()->whereTrue('is_current')->first();
```

Of course, you could make an accessor in your model to shorten this:

```
# User.php

public function getCurrentProviderAttribute()
{
    return $this->providers()->where('is_current', true)->first();
}
```

So now, you can do simply:

```
Auth::user()->current_provider;
```

Comment: This is quite good solution. For now I prefer Ruben's hotfix as it's more simple. Thank you guys